# Display specific content on singular custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-post-type

I'm trying to get a specific link to show in a `php` partial if it's on a `single-things.php` page.

I have the code in a `top-part.php` which I'm including on the `single-things.php` page:

```
<?php if (is_singular( 'things' ))  : ?>

  //Show content if it's on single-things.php post type

  <?php else : ?>

  //Display other content

 <?php endif; ?>
```

Main thing is that I have the `top-part.php` included on other pages as a partial so I *only* want to show that specific content if it's on the URL of the single item in the custom post type.

That *should* be working, right? Unless I'm missing something.

Comment: So in other words what you're looking for is a way to know when `top-part.php` is being included by `single-things.php`?

Comment: No, top part is included on `single-things.php` already. I want to check to see if it's on the 'single-things.php' page to show the alternate content.

Comment: What code do you have before your first conditional if?, you can use this alternative `global $post;  if(get_post_type($post->ID)=='things') `

Comment: BOOM! That worked. So the biggest thing I think was that I needed the `global $post;` since I after I checked that wasn't being queried higher up in the template files. Thanks!